# Calculating Reynolds number of ellipse in fluid

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics

I know Reynolds number is calculated from the formula by including length or diameter of an object in fluid.
I have a case where there is ellipse with 2a major and 2b axis. I hv learnt when the ellipse is horizontal with stream the charecteristics length is the major axis. But my doubt in when ellipse is inclined to the stream should I take the appropriate length along the stream or still the length of the ellipse?
Even when ellipse is perpendicular to the flow, is the charecteristic length minor axis?
Pl someone clarify.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty with Reynolds number is that the length scale (and often times the velocity scale) are both completely subjective, as you have identified. In standard nomenclature, an airfoil (or in your case, an ellipse) would use the freestream velocity as the velocity scale and the chord (semi-major axis) as the length scale. This is the assumed standard for aerodynamic analysis.

Your example of a vertical ellipse (ie. the semi-minor axis is aligned with the flow) changes the type of problem slightly because aerodynamicists don't generally consider things like that. However, a problem like that is similar to flow over a "fence", or flow over a "post", etc.. And in these problems, the height of the fence/post is the length scale of choice. For your ellipse, that would mean you still use the semi-major axis.

In general, you need to pick the length scale that is appropriate for the problem. For a wing, it makes sense to choose the chord of the wing and not the length of the conveyor belt that built the wing. For your ellipse in the configurations you listed, the semi-major axis is essentially always the length scale that controls the features of the flow. Other problems may not be so easy to determine and in these cases, you pick one (or several) and give Reynolds numbers based on all of them -- this is typical in turbulence where you might see a Reynolds number based on the integral scale, or the dissipation scales, or the Taylor microscale. All of these are valid and useful provided you state what system you use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your elaborate answer. I met with this scanario when I wanted to validate my code with published results. when i calculated drag and lift coefficients they were not equal to the available results. therefore was wondering do i make error in calculating Re. Thanks for clarifying.